# crash with ActivityNotFoundException on "GET GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES" click ( with Xiaomi device as an example )

Tags: android, crash, google-play-services

My app is using google maps, however on the devices without Google Play services, this map is not available and is replaced by the default text + button provided by google to get those services, like in the following picture:

[image]

My problem is that when this occurs on a Xiaomi device ( in China, the services provided by Google are blocked ), clicking on this button makes the app crash with the following error message:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1781)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3806)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3767)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:748)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4077)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4045)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19911)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5269)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:910)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:705)
```

I guess this error might occurs every time I will try to use a google service on a phone which doesn't have it.

So my question is how can I surround this with a try/catch block? I mean I'm using a google map fragment and then, I don't know how to access this button. It left a possible crash case on my app, which is not user friendly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if Google Play Service is installed with [GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context context)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context))

If this is not the case, you can use other providers to show the map.

> ***public int isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context context)***
>
> Verifies that Google Play services is installed and enabled on this device, and that the version installed on this device is no older than the one required by this client.
>
> Returns
> status code indicating whether there was an error. Can be one of following in ConnectionResult: SUCCESS, SERVICE_MISSING, SERVICE_UPDATING, SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_INVALID

Comment: This is planned ( I'm gonna use amap otherwhise ) but I would like to try/catch the events happening on this button click, as some devices are compatibles with the google play services and some others are not.

Comment: Hmm, I researched a bit and it seems that you are not the only person with this problem. Check this discussion, I hope this helps a bit: [Google Maps API 2 crashes when fetched Google Play Services without the Play app installed.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42543)